# Using Polymorphism with Templates

Tags: c++, templates, oop

Is it possible to use PolyMorphism when using Templates?

For example, I have a class called "Filters" and I have many different variations / classes of how the data can be filtered and therefore I initialise an object based on the Template (which type of filter is defined in main)

```
#include "Filter1.h"
#include "Filter2.h"
template<typename T>
class Filters {

public:

    void Filter(vector<double> &vec) {

        T type;

        type.Filter(vec);
    }
};


// class Filter1
class Filter1 {
   public:

      void Filter(vector<double> &vec) {

         // Code for "Filter1"

      }
};

// MAIN

int main() {
   vector<double> sample; // this is a sample vector
   Filters<Filter1> exam1;
   exam1.filter(sample);
}
```

This would work, however, in "Filter2" let's say we have more paramaters we pass:

```
 class Filter2 {

  public:
     void Filter(vector<double> &vec, double point)
     {
         // Filter 2
     }        
 };
```

And then the main:

```
int main()
{
    vector<double> sample;
    double point = 9;

    Filters<Filter2> exam;
    exam.Filter(sample, point);
}
```

This would not work, because, "Filter" in "Filters" only accepts 1 paramater.

The problem that I am having is the fact that the Filters differer in the paramaters they accept. For example "Filter1" passes through a 2D vector, and a double but the Filter method definition in this class only accepts a 1D vector.

I was thinking (Theoretically) I could have a switch statement ("T") that offers a initialises the different classes.

Any ideas would be appreciated .

Comment: `Filter` could accept a `T` instead (since that's what it needs after all), but that might only work because you wrote a simple example.

Comment: @LucDanton Shall I update my post and include a more complex in-depth example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do generic programming with templates, you need to code against interfaces. I'm not using the OOP meaning of the term here -- the wider meaning instead.

As an example, here is a function template that codes against the Random-Access Iterator concept-like interface:

```
template<typename It>
typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type
sum(It first, It last)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type diff_t;
    diff_t const size = last - first;

    typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type accum = 0;
    for(diff_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        accum += first[i];
    }

    return accum;
}
```

(This example is of course bogus, the intent here is to show multiple Random-Access Iterator operations.)

Because we specify in our contract that `It` is a Random-Access Iterator, we know `sum` has access to:

- member-types `std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type` and `std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type`, which are types that can be initialized from the result of `operator[]` and `operator-` respectively
- operations on `It` like `operator-` and `operator[]`, which are *not* available with e.g. Bidirectional Iterators

As such `sum` can be used with `std::vector<int>::iterator`, `std::deque<double>::const_iterator` and `long*`, which are all different types which may differ in some aspects but at least are all models of the Random-Access Iterator concepts.

(The observant will have noticed that by using `0` and `+=` we in turn require in our contract that the `value_type` be an arithmetic-like type. That's again an interface we code against!)

Then when designing your `Filters` which you apparently intend to use as `Filters<FilterLike>`, you need to ask yourself what is the common minimal interface that a `FilterLike` needs to fulfill. If there is some `FilterX` which *almost* is a `FilterLike` except perhaps for some operation, here are some options:

- as you mention in your question, wherever `Filters` uses that particular operation you can special-case it so that `FilterX` is specially handled -- this is the probably the *worst* thing you can do. It's brittle in that you have to do it at every site where you need the operation (even if it looks like it's only one right now, what about in the future?); it's inconvenient in that no, you can't switch on a type inside a function body of a class template function member (you have to use different techniques which are verbose and unobvious); and it introduces coupling in that `Filters` has to know about `FilterX` -- why should it care?
- write an explicit specialization for `Filters<FilterX>`. This is much like the above, but is an interesting option when `FilterX` differ not in just one or two operations. Unlike the previous solution, this isn't as brittle because the primary template is left untouched and all the `FilterX` specific stuff is put in the same spot. If on the other hand half of `FilterX` already behave like a `Filter`, then that must mean there is either half the code of `Filters<FilterLike>` that ends duplicated or some extra work is needed to refactor out the common code between `Filters<Filter>` and `Filters<FilterX>`. Hence the amount of coupling varies -- if the primary template doesn't have to know about this explicit specialization then it's a good option, and you don't even have to bundle the explicit specialization with the primary template
- write an `AdaptedFilterX` that is a model of the `FilterLike` interface and forwards all its operation to an underlying `FilterX`. If you have several `FilterX`, `FilterY` that are all almost models of `Filter` but have a common interface, you can write an `AdaptedFilter<FilterX>` -- in a sense the `AdaptedFilter` template 'transforms' a model of a `FilterXLike` into a model of a `FilterLike`

As an aside, if you were using C++11 you could have written `Filter` to accept arbitrary arguments to construct a `FilterLike` with:

```
template<typename... Args>
void Filter(Args&&... args)
{
    FilterLike filter(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // go on using filter...
}
```

It's perhaps simpler (and works for C++03) to just accept a `FilterLike` though:

```
void Filter(FilterLike filter)
{
   // go on using filter...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are depending on templates another way would be to pass filter that template as argument. 
Mostly filter are dependent on standart operations like + - /. Therefore you can overload that functions in your Vector2D, Vector1D ... classes and your filter function will call that methods automatically.

Hope this helps a bit :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I meant like.. Filter has: Filter(vector<double> &data) WHEREAS Filter1 is: Filter1(vector<double> &data, double value); etc.. And if I call Filters<Filter1>filter1(DATA, theType); it would throw up an error